How to upload a Arduino Program to a BARTH STG-850 via ST-LINK/V2 ISOL
I have a Barth Electronik STG-850 micro PLC, the ST-LINK/V2 ISOL Programmer and a VK-35 programming cable from Barth.
I did everything according to the docs
But I don't get a Virtual COM Port, just a USB Device "STM32 STLink".


That doesn't show up in the Arduino IDE, so no download is possible.
I tried my normal Win 11 Pro PC as well as another running Windows 10. Same behaviour on both machines.
If I run the "ST-LINK_CLI.exe" with the "-List" Argument as described in the docs, I see that the ST-LINK is found but I guess that works through the USB interface:
.\ST-LINK_CLI.exe -List
STM32 ST-LINK CLI v3.0.0.0
STM32 ST-LINK Command Line Interface

--- Available ST-LINK Probes List ---

ST-LINK Probe 0:
     SN: 32FF6C063051563945572143
     FW: V2J45S7

----------------------------------

Does anybody know what I need to do in order to get this up and running?

https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32/wiki/Upload-methods#arduino-integration

I finally figured it out :-)
I was able to read the target data with ST-LINK_CLI.exe -c SWD UR
When I tried to programm the STD-850 from the Arduino IDE, I saw in the error message that a script called stlink_upload.bat that is in the same directory as the ST-LINK_CLI.exe (C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\STM32\tools\STM32Tools\2017.7.13/tools/win/stlink_upload.bat)
After opening this file I saw that it programs the target with echo "" | stlink\ST-LINK_CLI.exe -c SWD -P %str% 0x8000000 -Rst -Run
I realized that this command was missing the UR parameter.
So the line has to be
echo "" | stlink\ST-LINK_CLI.exe -c SWD UR -P %str% 0x8000000 -Rst -Run
After adding it I'm able to program the STD-850 out of my Arduino IDE as expected. No need for a virtual serial port.
